# How to convert DateTime format from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Tags: apex, datetime, date, conversion

I have converted a Date into DateTime format, and it is returning me the hour format in **00:00:00** but I want it to be in **23:59:59**

```
Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2021,2,1);
```

This returns the output as **2021-02-01 00:00:00**

When I try to convert this to the **23:59:59** hour format by using the below code

```
DateTime startDateConvertTwo = DateTime.newInstance(startDate, Time.newInstance(23, 59, 59, 0));
```

It is pushing the date to next day and returning the value of **2021-02-02 07:59:59**

I  tried to sort this out by changing the values of Time.newInstance by adding it as **Time.newInstance(15, 59, 59, 0)** by doing which I get the expected result. But is it the right way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Please let me know if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not considering timezones. Salesforce accepts input of and presents Datetime values in user timezone, but fundamentally stores the values in UTC (GMT).

If you are looking at the output of `System.debug(startDateConvertTwo);` and you think this is giving you the wrong date/time, that's because `System.debug` shows the underlying date/time values in UTC (GMT).

I suggest you are in a timezone with offset -8 hours. What you have done in your code is perfectly fine and the resulting Datetime value, if stored in a field or output to the UI in some way (other than via System.debug directly) it will have the value you want.

Comment: Oh I hadn't taken the timezones into consideration. Thank you for the answer Phil